# randomForest Need at least two classes to do classification

Tags: classification, random-forest

I have a dataset Data_Model, which I want to build a classifier on the "response" variable. I did the following first:

`D<-Data_Model`

`D$response<-factor(D$response,levels = c(0,1))`

Then I ran:

`FOREST_model <- randomForest(response~., data=D, ntree=3000,na.action=na.omit)`
I got the following error:

`**Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  Need at least two classes to do classification.**`

However, if I check the levels in "response", there are two levels in it:

`table(D$response,exclude = NULL)
    0     1  <NA> 
11401  5612     0`

and if I do:

`class(str(D$response))
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I got it myself, the problem was not 'response', the problem was several columns have a lot of missing values (or all missing values), after dropping them, it worked.